# How to get a count value from server into json in android?

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to retrieve the number of rows in my server table using json parsing and php in android.
I have done the following coding in php and I am getting the value also, but I don 't know how to proceed with the json. Please guide me step by step what to do or where I am going wrong. My codes and error logs are as follows:

php code:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","user","pswd");
mysql_select_db("demo");    
$username= (isset($_POST['receivenumber'])) ? $_POST['receivenumber'] : '';
$q=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(receivenumber) FROM `addtasknew` where `receivenumber` = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
print (json_encode($row));
mysql_close();
?>
```

json codes in android

```
   String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mydomainname.org/task/getmytaskcount.php");
            ArrayList<NameValuePair>  nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
           // String h="123";
            //nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("to",h.toString()));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("receivenumber","9595959595"));

             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

            Log.e("log_tag", "connection success "+nameValuePairs);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connection fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    try
    {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,HTTP.UTF_8),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");

            }
            is.close();

            result=sb.toString();
          Log.e("log_tag", "result "+result.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
           Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " Input reading fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    try
    {

                 // I don't know wht to do here to get the count value
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

          Log.w("Lengh",""+jArray);
             }
    catch(JSONException e)
    {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

error logs:

```
  E/log_tag(2386): result ?{"COUNT(receivenumber)":"2"}
  E/log_tag(2386): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value {"COUNT(receivenumber)":"2"} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: try this `$q=mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(receivenumber) AS count FROM `addtasknew` where `receivenumber` = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: I am getting the count value correctly, but i don't know how to receive it in json in android

Comment: pls have a look at this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to interpret your `JSON` as a `JSONArray` but it's a `JSONObject`.

To retrieve your value try this:

```
JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);
String count= jObj.getString("COUNT(receivenumber)");
```

You can check this [tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-json-tutorial-create-and-parse-json-data.html) to learn more about `JSON` in android.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
          try {
        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(result);
        Log.i("COUNT",jObj.getString("COUNT") + " COUNT");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and change the sql query like

"SELECT COUNT(receivenumber) as COUNT FROM `addtasknew` where `receivenumber` = '$username'";